# How to get `top` for a specific user only?

Tags: top

How can I read `top` in bash only for one user? I don't want it to display data for other users.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From `man top`:

```
-u : Monitor by user as:     -u somebody
     Monitor only processes with an effective UID or user name matching
     that given.
```

So, if you run `top -u root` you'll get only `root` processes.

Comment: By the way, as of v1.33.1, this does not work with busybox's top.

Comment: In a **running** instance of `top`, press `u` to filter processes by user. From the help (use `?` to show it): "u,U,o,O . Filter by: 'u'/'U' effective/any user; 'o'/'O' other criteria"

Answer (score 0):

If you already started top, you can also press the `u` key and enter the *username* in the status line.

In case you want to show all users again (make the selection undone), press the `=` key or respectively the `+` key to  clear the selection criteria in all top windows.